# Python project dependency on external Git repo

Tags: python, package, pythonpath

I have a project that depends on an external Github repo.  What's the correct way to include this dependency in my project?

Note: the dependency is not a pip package, but a Python project hosted in Github, so I can't just pip install the package

I've been thinking of creating an `extern` folder with all my external Github dependencies and adding it to `PYTHONPATH` but this feels kludgy:

```
/baseRepoDir/
   my_project/
   extern/
      github_project/
```

Then do the following from Bash:

`export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/baseRepoDir/extern`

Inside my Python project code import the Github project as a package:

```
from github_project import my_required_module
```

Will this approach work?
Is there a nicer way of doing this?

Comment: Did you know `pip` can install packages from Github and any GIt repositories?

Comment: Thanks @phd, but is this repo formatted as an installable package? https://github.com/hollance/BlazeFace-PyTorch

Comment: This one isn't. So `git clone` + `$PYTHONPATH` (or `sys.path`) is the only way, alas.